PySTAC: getting the Catalogue from the Copernicus Dataspace Ecosystem
I am trying to retrieve the product catalogue from the Copernicus Dataspace Ecosystem (CDSE) using the STAC API and PySTAC.
Following the PySTAC tutorial, I tried the following:
from pystac import Catalog, Collection, get_stac_version

root_catalog = Catalog.from_file("https://catalogue.dataspace.copernicus.eu/stac/")
root_catalog.describe()

But it results in an empty catalogue:
* <Catalog id=Catalogue>

If I do the same with USGS, it works and I can retrieve the collections:
root_catalog = Catalog.from_file("https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/stac-server/")
root_catalog.describe()

* <Catalog id=stac-server>
    * <Collection id=landsat-c2l2-sr>
    * <Collection id=landsat-c2l2-st>
    * <Collection id=landsat-c2ard-st>
    * <Collection id=landsat-c2l2alb-bt>
    * <Collection id=landsat-c2l3-fsca>
    * <Collection id=landsat-c2ard-bt>
    * <Collection id=landsat-c2l1>
    * <Collection id=landsat-c2l3-ba>
    * <Collection id=landsat-c2l2alb-st>
    * <Collection id=landsat-c2ard-sr>
    * <Collection id=landsat-c2l2alb-sr>
    * <Collection id=landsat-c2l2alb-ta>
    * <Collection id=landsat-c2l3-dswe>
    * <Collection id=landsat-c2ard-ta>

What am I doing wrong with the CDSE?

Tl;dr: because the Copernicus STAC endpoint is an API (not a static catalog), use pystac-client. Check out the "Dynamic and Static Catalogs" section of https://stacspec.org/en/about/stac-spec/ for more.
Details
pystac's response is correct, there are no child links in the root catalog:
$ curl -s https://catalogue.dataspace.copernicus.eu/stac/ | jq -c '.links.[] | { rel: .rel, href: .href }'
{"rel":"root","href":"https://catalogue.dataspace.copernicus.eu/stac"}
{"rel":"self","href":"https://catalogue.dataspace.copernicus.eu/stac"}
{"rel":"service-desc","href":"https://catalogue.dataspace.copernicus.eu/stac/api"}
{"rel":"conformance","href":"https://catalogue.dataspace.copernicus.eu/stac/conformance"}
{"rel":"data","href":"https://catalogue.dataspace.copernicus.eu/stac/collections"}
{"rel":"search","href":"https://catalogue.dataspace.copernicus.eu/stac/search"}
{"rel":"search","href":"https://catalogue.dataspace.copernicus.eu/stac/search"}

Whereas the USGS server has child links:
$ curl -s https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/stac-server/ | jq -c '.links.[] | { rel: .rel, href: .href }'      
{"rel":"self","href":"https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/stac-server/"}
{"rel":"root","href":"https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/stac-server/"}
{"rel":"conformance","href":"https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/stac-server/conformance"}
{"rel":"data","href":"https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/stac-server/collections"}
{"rel":"search","href":"https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/stac-server/search"}
{"rel":"service-desc","href":"https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/stac-server/api"}
{"rel":"service-doc","href":"https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/stac-server/api.html"}
{"rel":"docs","href":"https://stac-utils.github.io/stac-server/"}
{"rel":"child","href":"https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/stac-server/collections/landsat-c2l2-sr"}
{"rel":"child","href":"https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/stac-server/collections/landsat-c2l2-st"}
{"rel":"child","href":"https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/stac-server/collections/landsat-c2ard-st"}
{"rel":"child","href":"https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/stac-server/collections/landsat-c2l2alb-bt"}
{"rel":"child","href":"https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/stac-server/collections/landsat-c2l3-fsca"}
{"rel":"child","href":"https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/stac-server/collections/landsat-c2ard-bt"}
{"rel":"child","href":"https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/stac-server/collections/landsat-c2l1"}
{"rel":"child","href":"https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/stac-server/collections/landsat-c2l3-ba"}
{"rel":"child","href":"https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/stac-server/collections/landsat-c2l2alb-st"}
{"rel":"child","href":"https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/stac-server/collections/landsat-c2ard-sr"}
{"rel":"child","href":"https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/stac-server/collections/landsat-c2l2alb-sr"}
{"rel":"child","href":"https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/stac-server/collections/landsat-c2l2alb-ta"}
{"rel":"child","href":"https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/stac-server/collections/landsat-c2l3-dswe"}
{"rel":"child","href":"https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/stac-server/collections/landsat-c2ard-ta"}

Instead of using pystac, use pystac-client:
from pystac_client import Client

client = Client.open("https://catalogue.dataspace.copernicus.eu/stac/")
for collection in client.get_all_collections():
    print("-", collection.id)

Output:
- COP-DEM
- S2GLC
- TERRAAQUA
- SENTINEL-3
- SENTINEL-5P
- SENTINEL-1-RTC
- SENTINEL-1
- SMOS
- LANDSAT-7
- CCM
- LANDSAT-5
- LANDSAT-8
- ENVISAT
- SENTINEL-6
- GLOBAL-MOSAICS
- SENTINEL-2

